Looker Studio Community Connector Stepped Configuration Error
I am trying to rebuild our Looker Studio community connector after Google upgraded the Google Business Profiles API
-the getConfig function defines certain user parameters
-the documentation seems a bit thin to me, but as I understand it, setting "setIsSteppedConfig" to "true" lets us capture a user's selection (in configParams) and then use that selection later.
-this community connector allows a user to select from a list of Google Business Profile locations. We populated a drop down with locations and the user selects one--this part works fine, we can see a list of GBP Locations in Looker Studio when we connect using our partially-coded community connector.
-Currently, I get an error in Apps Script console when I run getConfig(request) that says " TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'configParams')" and then the line number for the 3rd line of my code below
-First question is ... is there a way to suppress that error so I can at least move forward with building and debugging (I am literally going a line at a time here)?
-Next, how do I return the value of ".setValue(option.value)" (with that value, we can incude the id number in an API Call)

`
function getConfig(request) {
  var config = cc.getConfig();
  var configParams = request.configParams;
  var isFirstRequest = configParams === undefined;
  if (isFirstRequest) {
    config.setIsSteppedConfig(true);
  }

  // Initialize the OAuth2 service
  let gmbService = getOAuthService();

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://mybusinessaccountmanagement.googleapis.com/v1/accounts", {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + gmbService.getAccessToken()
    }
  });

  //Strip the account ID out of the JSON output with a regex and cache
  var regExp = /[0-9]{10,40}/g;
  //var responseParsed = JSON.parse(response)[0];
  //var fullName = responseParsed.name;
  var accountId = regExp.exec(response);

  //With the account ID we pull a list of locations from GBP
  var bob = accountId[0];
  var requestURL = 'https://mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com/v1/accounts/' + bob + '/locations?readMask=Title,storefrontAddress,name&pageSize=100';
  var locationList = UrlFetchApp.fetch(requestURL, {
    headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + gmbService.getAccessToken() },
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  });

  //Parse the response into a Javascript object
  var parsedLocationList = JSON.parse(locationList);

  //Create object array of location data options
  var opts = []
  //Loop through the location data and add the relevant fields of each item to the option array
  var i = 0;

  parsedLocationList.locations.forEach(function (opt) {
    var city = "Service Area Only";
    if (typeof opt.storefrontAddress !== 'undefined') { city = opt.storefrontAddress.locality; }
    opts[i] = {
      "label": opt.title + " | " + city, //Use city name to differentiate same-named businesses
      "value": opt.name
    };
    i++;
  });

  //Alphabetize the options
  opts.sort(function (a, b) {
    var nameA = a.label.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
    var nameB = b.label.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
    if (nameA < nameB) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (nameA > nameB) {
      return 1;
    }
    // case: names are equal
    return 0;
  });

  var newOpts = opts.map(item => {
    return ".addOption(config.newOptionBuilder().setLabel('" + item.label + "').setValue('" + item.value + "'))"
  });

  config.setDateRangeRequired(true);
  config.newInfo()
    .setId('instructions')
    .setText('Hello Tasty, Please Select a Business Location.');

  config.newTextInput()
    .setId('package')
    .setName('Success, You Have Connected to the Following Account:')
    .setHelpText('...there is no help here.')
    .setPlaceholder(bob);

  var selectConfig = config.newSelectSingle()
    .setId('gbpLocation')
    .setName('Choose a Gooogle Busines Profile from the Drop Down: ')
    .setHelpText('...there is no help here.')
    .setAllowOverride(true)
  opts.forEach(function (option) {
    selectConfig.addOption(
      config.newOptionBuilder()
        .setLabel(option.label)
        .setValue(option.value)
    );
  });

  if (!isFirstRequest) {
    config.setIsSteppedConfig(false)

  };

  return config.build();

}

Just a lot of debugging. I tried to set a value for var configParams so the error wouldn't be thrown, that didn't work.
If there is someone that is skilled at writing these community connectors, we are open to paying for some coding help.
